# Problem referencing Quicktime plugin generated and inserted by Jquery

Tags: jquery, quicktime

I've got a problem where I generated a Quicktime plgin using the AC_Quicktime plugin, and then drop this into a  using jquery. In Firefox I can then reference the created plugin using it's objectid, but in IE 6.0 this doesn't seem to work.

I've tried using jquery to reference the plugin... but can't seem to do so.

Here's the code that generates the plugin parameters:-

```
var movie1 = QT_GenerateOBJECTText(
        currentfile, playerwidth, playerheight, "",
        "controller","false",
        "obj#id", "movie1",
        "emb#id","qt_movie1",
        "postdomevents","True",
        "emb#NAME","movie1",
            "enablejavascript","true",
        "autoplay",boolplaying,
        "scale","aspect",
        "pluginspage","http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/"
            );

            $("#player").html(movie1);
```

I then check that the plugin has been generated using this, and then do some stuff with it:-

```
if ($("#qt_movie1").length > 0)
            {
              alert('clip loaded up');
            //clip with embedded id 'qt_movie1' must be loaded so wait a bit then run timecode()
            //showEvents('now run timecode');

            //calculate duration
            Id = window.setTimeout("timecode()",500);
            }
```

In Firefox the alert (for debug purposes) fires off but it doesn't in IE. In another simple function I stop the movie using this:-

```
function stopmovie()
{

  document.movie1.Stop();
  boolplaying = false;

}
```

Again 'document.movie1' works to reference the movie in Firefox, but not IE.

Is there a jquery selector I can use for the quicktime plugin? Or is there another way to reference the plugin?

Cheers.

Jon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer.... IE 6.0 doesn't seem to recognise the id of the newly created player using the attribute "emb#id","qt_movie1".

Changing the attribute to "id" fixes the problem. I'm sure this is contrary to the Quicktime spec but hey.

Answer (score 0):

I remember a similar question about another type of embedded object.  Apparently, IE only creates these objects when the page is loaded, so inserting it after the fact with javascript just won't work.  (Someone please let me know, if this is just bad info.)